# Flask-WTForms never validates even when {{ form.hidden_tag() }} is present

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have given a snippet of my `forms.py`, `routes.py` and `createPatient.html` (relevant screenshot). I had a previous form for login of the same application where I faced the same error for which I deleted the old project and started this new one.

**route.py**

```
@app.route("/createPatient",methods=['GET','POST'])
def create():
    form1 = createPatient(request.form)
    if form1.validate_on_submit():
        print("Sucess")
        return redirect('/index')
    else:
        print("Unsuccessful")

    return render_template("createPatient.html", form = form1)
```

the output of this when I entered `form1.validate()` is `false` and `form1.errors` is `{}` and prints unsuccessful

***forms.py***

```
class createPatient(FlaskForm):
    ssn_id = IntegerField("SSN ID", validators = [DataRequired()])
    name = StringField("Patient Name",validators=[DataRequired()])
    age = IntegerField("Patient Age",validators=[DataRequired()])
    doa = DateField("Date of Admission",validators=[DataRequired()])
    tob = SelectField("Type of Bed", choices = [('General Ward'),('Semi Sharing'),('Single Room')],validators =[DataRequired()])
    address = StringField("Address", validators=[DataRequired()])
    city = StringField("City", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min = 6 ,max = 20)])
    state = StringField("State", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max = 30)])
    create = SubmitField("Create Patient")
```

no syntatical error in the above file

***createPatient.html***

```
<form name = "createPatient" action= "/createPatient" method="POST" >

    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    <p>
        {{ form.ssn_id.label }}
        {{ form.ssn_id(size = 9 ) }}
        {% for error in form.ssn_id.errors %}
            <span class="error-message">*{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}<br>
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ form.name.label }}
        {{ form.name(size = 35 ) }}
        {% for error in form.name.errors %}
            <span class="error-message">*{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}<br>
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ form.age.label }}
        {{ form.age(size = 35 ) }}
        {% for error in form.age.errors %}
            <span class="error-message">*{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}<br>
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.doa.label }}
        {{ form.doa(size = 35 ) }}
        {% for error in form.doa.errors %}
            <span class="error-message">*{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}<br>
    </p>
    
        {{ form.tob.label }}
        {{ form.tob() }}
        {% for error in form.tob.errors %}
            <span class="error-message">*{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}<br>
    
    <p>
        {{ form.address.label }}
        {{ form.address(size = 35 ) }}
        {% for error in form.address.errors %}
            <span clas="error-message">*{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}<br>
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.city.label }}
        {{ form.city(size = 35 ) }}
        {% for error in form.city.errors %}
            <span clas="error-message">*{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}<br>
    </p>
    <p>
        {{ form.state.label }}
        {{ form.state(size = 35 ) }}
        {% for error in form.state.errors %}
            <span clas="error-message">*{{ error }}</span>
        {% endfor %}<br>
    </p>

   <p> {{ form.create ()}} </p>

</form>
```

**config.py**

```
import os

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
```

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask 
from config import Config
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

app =Flask(__name__)
app['SECRET_KEY']= Config.SECRET_KEY
```

Comment: You should print form.errors when it's unsuccessful, wtform returns some useful informations.

Comment: I did print out and it returned everytime an empty dictionary {}

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, CSRF tokens are generated using `SECRET_KEY`. In your **config.py** file, I see `SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)`. Each time you reload your app, your key will be replaced with new one. This can cause CSRF errors.

Instead try to generate your key externally and place it inside .env or config.py:

```py
SECRET_KEY = 'super-secret-random-key'
```

or

```py
import os
class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but i still encounter the same error. I trued the former part which is maintaining a constant key. But still form does'nt validate and it is still posting a GET method.

Comment: Assuming you are trying to submit the form in the shell, could you please share what you write there?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the shell over here btw I am a newbie, It would be great if you could be a bit descriptive.

Comment: No problem. Are you typing `form1.errors` into terminal (or cmd in Windows)? If yes, then what parameters do you use when instatiating the form object. 
E.g: `form1 = ProfileForm(MultiDict([('first_name', 'John'),('last_name', 'Doe')]))`

Comment: No I didnt do any instantiation as of now all I wanted to check was whether the form validates my input. Thats all because of which if you can see my createPatient route I didnt do any activities.

Comment: But you must have been typing `form1.validate()` and `form1.errors` into somewhere. I'm trying to re-produce the results you stated in your question (`False` and `{}`) to figure out the problem.

Comment: So yeah I've been getting the same results in my cmd as I've mentioned in my query. I did instantiate my form using the form1 object but I never did pass in any params.

Comment: That might be the problem. If you try to submit and validate a form with field `validators=[DataRequired()]` the form wouldn't submit. Try submitting it with all necessary fields and let me know if it works. And run form1.errors afterwards to see if it returns any information we can use. Also here's a [link](https://overiq.com/flask-101/form-handling-in-flask/) for more information on wtforms with Flask